# How to change the height of a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, size, jcombobox

I have a class extending JFrame and I want to add a JComboBox on a panel. When I did this, the JComboBox size is very large. I want to change its size, but don't know how to do this. `.setSize()` and `.setPreferredSize()` are not working. The layout of the JFrame must be GridLayout.

```
public CountryController() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 600));
    //panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 1, Color.BLACK));
    panel1.add(new JLabel("Some text:"));


    //list countries
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jDropDown);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    jDropDown.setOpaque(true);
    jDropDown.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 0, 1, Color.BLACK));
    jDropDown.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    panel1.add(scrollPane);

    getContentPane().add(panel1);
}
```

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Try adding a blank `JLabel` to `panel1`: `panel1.add(new JLabel(""));`  This might fill in the space at the bottom of the cell, which may be what you want.

Comment: *"JFrame layout must be GridLayout."*  That's a requirement that means you cannot get what you asked for!  As an aside, very few GUIs use just one layout.  Try combining them.

Comment: @DannyDaglas, as always I have to write 'hindu code', result)) http://i.piccy.info/i9/d5aa2cb7206d1651e2fa13acbad2772e/1424439526/3532/873522/Bezymiannyi2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is the method `setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 25))`. In `BoxLayout` components are added with max size and this method helps me to change the max size.